# Custom 404 page not working on further directories

Tags: html, apache2

I'm trying to create a custom 404 error page running apache2 on ubuntu. I put the relevant line of code in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf ("ErrorDocument 404 /404.html"). However, when the page not found includes a backslash (e.g. mywebsite.com/asdf/asdf), the assets I've included on the 404.html document are unable to load, despite loading when not calling from a further directory (e.g. mywebsite.com/asdf). Let me know if anyone more experienced can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my 404.html document I wasn't using src="/myimage.png", I was using src="myimage.png". Adding the forward slash fixed my issue. Sorry for the poor question.